# display image[] in listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, listview

I'd like to display an `Image[]` in a listview but don't know how. I searched the web and the consensus seemed to be that an `ImageList` was to be preferred for this. It works and displays correctly, but it doesn't suit my needs.

How would I convert this code to work with an `Image[]` instead of an `ImageList`?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

     string dir = (string)e.Argument;
     imageArr = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpeg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

     picList = new ImageList();

     toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Generating thumbnails...";

     for (int i = 0; i < imageArr.Length; i++)
     {
         Image img = Image.FromFile(imageArr[i]);
         int width = img.Width / 10;
         int height = img.Height / 10;
         Image pic = img.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, new IntPtr());
         picList.Images.Add(pic);

         int procent = ((i + 1) * 100) / imageArr.Length;
         bw.ReportProgress(procent);
     }

     bw.ReportProgress(0);
     toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "";

     populateListView(picList);
 }

 private delegate void populateListViewDelegate(ImageList picList);

 private void populateListView(ImageList picList)
 {
     if (InvokeRequired)
     {
         this.Invoke(new populateListViewDelegate(populateListView), picList);
         return;
     }

     Size thumbSize = new Size(200, 141);
     listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
     picList.ImageSize = thumbSize;
     listView1.LargeImageList = picList;

     toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Adding thumbnails to listview...";

     for (int i = 0; i < picList.Images.Count; i++)
     {
         ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
         item.ImageIndex = i;
         listView1.Items.Add(item);

         int procent = ((i + 1) * 100) / picList.Images.Count;
         bw.ReportProgress(procent);
     }

     bw.ReportProgress(0);
     toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "";
 }
```

Obviously `int width` and `int height` don't work as ImageList has the same size for all images, if I understood that correctly, but I didn't know that at the time, that's why my lazy self has left that code there.

Basically, the "needs" I mentioned earlier is that these "thumbnails" should be able to have different sizes.

Any help with workarounds, tips on my problem or maybe I should take a different approach?

Comment: If you need to show thumbnails of different sizes, a ListView won't help you -- a ListView can't show rows of different heights. If you are only showing an image, then a ListBox would be a better fit for your needs.

Comment: But the images could, theoretically, be of different sizes while the rows are uniform in size. Couldn't one set a limit as to how big a thumbnail can be as so it doesn't exceed the size of the row? I need to display a couple of thousand thumbnails at a time, preferrably the sizes should be able to differ, but the differences would be really small, such as difference due to orientation; landscape, portrait. Any tips on how/what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ImageSize` before adding Images. If you change the `ImageSize`, any previously added images are deleted. [See the Remarks here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagesize.aspx)

You probably want to set the ColorDepth to 32 bits as well before adding any images.